# How to get End of Day from given datetime

Tags: informix

I want to convert the given DateTime to the end of day. This should be a Informix sql.

For example.
 If pass date like '2019-02-13 13:52:00' need to convert this to '2019-02-13 23:59:59'

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I manged to convert this like TO_CHAR(p_start_dt,'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')

Answer (score 1):

Adding an alternative solution to the one used by OP, using only time and interval types:

```sql
SELECT
    -- Create a datetime from a string, only used for this example
    '2019-02-13 13:52:00'::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND AS original_datetime,
    -- Truncate the original datetime, removing the 'hour to second' part
    '2019-02-13 13:52:00'::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND::DATETIME YEAR TO DAY AS truncated_datetime,
    -- Adding a datetime with an interval will return a datetime
    INTERVAL( 23:59:59 ) HOUR( 2 ) TO SECOND AS interval_to_add,
    -- Adding an 'hour to second' interval requires that the datetime 
    -- also has the 'hour to second' part, so cast again from 'year to day'
    -- to 'year to second'  
    ( '2019-02-13 13:52:00'::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND::DATETIME YEAR TO DAY::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND ) + 
        INTERVAL( 23:59:59 ) HOUR( 2 ) TO SECOND AS calculated_datetime
FROM
    sysmaster:sysdual
;

original_datetime   truncated_datetime interval_to_add calculated_datetime

2019-02-13 13:52:00 2019-02-13          23:59:59       2019-02-13 23:59:59
```

The format used for displaying the `DATETIME` will depend of your environment setup ( environment variables like locale settings, `DBDATE`, `GL_DATE`, `GL_DATETIME`, etc ) .

Comment: `SELECT EXTEND(EXTEND(DATETIME(2019-02-13 13:52:00) YEAR TO SECOND, YEAR TO DAY) + 1 UNITS DAY, YEAR TO SECOND) - 1 UNITS SECOND` — alternative literal notations, the EXTEND function, and different ways of calculating 1 second before the end of the day. :D . The double EXTEND is about as painful as the casting.

Answer (score -1):

*(('2019-02-13 13:52:00' :: datetime year to second) :: date + 1) :: datetime year to second - 1 units second*